# Loading PHP file into DIV via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wrapper

Say I have an `index.php` that loads a `page.php` into the `div` of class '`wrapper`'.

`page.php` in turn has its own links and I want it so that when you click on one of these links it loads the respective page into the SAME '`wrapper`' `div`.

Similarly that loaded page might have its own links and I want to continue loading content into the same div. How might I achieve this chain effect of pages?

Comment: are you using vanilla JS, or a library like jQuery to load the AJAX?

Comment: Put `page.php` in an `<iframe>`

Comment: I'm using jQuery......and i'd prefer not to use iframe for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery / AJAX is your friend here:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
        var go = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {m: 'ajax', // POST Variables go here...
                linkID: $(this).val()} // $(this).val() is the value of the link clicked
        })
        .done(function(results) {
            $('#resultsDiv').html(results); // This is where your results go
        })
        .fail(function(msg) {
            alert("Error:" + msg);
        })
        .always(function() {
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'd need to see more code to give you a true copy/past answer but this is what you can use to detect which button was clicked, which content to load, and where to put the results.

Comment: It would be better to use a delegate here otherwise this would need to run every time new content was loaded... `$(document).on('click', 'div.wrapper a[href]', function (e) { /* your link handling */});`

Answer (score 1):

I would put the AJAX call into a function:

```
function loadWrapper($url){
    $('#wrapper').load($url+' > *',function(){
        $(this).on('click','a',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            loadWrapper($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
}
```

Then on page load assign the click to any item on the page that loads initially:

```
$('.LinkClass').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loadWrapper($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

And, of course, your original load:

```
loadWrapper('page.php');
```

The callback in the function will allow click events to fire on the loaded links, as well as any other links you may add in the future you want to load in `.Wrapper`. Just give those links the class `LinkClass` (or whatever you want) and you're good to go.

Comment: did you include the loadWrapper function call in your existing `$(document).ready` call? I got rid of the wrapper to avoid confusion, just put the `loadWrapper` call in your existing `ready` function. **edit:** i just noticed that you were experiencing the same issue with someone else's answer. have you successfully loaded `page.php` in the past? does it load in your browser without AJAX? because the page itself may be broken.

Comment: Yes, I included loadWrapper. Also page.php works in the browser by itself.

Comment: and `page.php` is in the same folder as the page `index.php`? or is it in a subfolder?

Comment: yup. its in the same folder.

Comment: i tried simply this: <script typ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#wrapper").load("page.php");
    });
</script> but it still doesn't show page.php.....

Comment: if you copy/pasted my code, it wouldnt. wrapper is the ID, not the class as you said in the OP. ill change my answer.

Comment: no no. i changed your code to wrapper before after copy/paste.

Comment: alright if you're unable to load the page with a simple load, something else is going on. changing my answer to try something else, which is getting all the children of `page.php`. if that doesnt work, then something is going on that you need to debug. something more basic, like making sure to call the jquery library script before your own js file.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var activateLinks = function() {
    $('.wrapper a[href]').click(function(){
        $('.wrapper').load($(this).attr('href'), activateLinks);
        return false;
    });
}

$('.wrapper').load('page.php', activateLinks);
```

or else

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'a[href]', function() {
    $('.wrapper').load($(this).attr('href');
    return false;
}
$('.wrapper').load('page.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a delegate is best this way you dont have to run handler attavchment for the links on the new page. They are handled automatically.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.wrapper a[href]', 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (html) {
       $('div.wrapper').html(html);
    });
});
```